# Using column names in R in across and summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate some summary values in my data. The interesting columns in the dataframe are named `exppw...._1003` and `pw...._1003` where `....` stands for e.g `0506`, `0607` and so on. The data in column `exppw...._1003` are derived from an experiment whereas the data in column `pw...._1003` are derived from our "standard procedure".

I would like to compare summary values for two corresponding columns, e.g. `pw0708_1003` and `exppw0708_1003`.

```
rt2020_2 %>% 
  select(id_intern, persGew, matches("exppw...._1003"), matches("pw...._1003")) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("pw"), 
               list(
                 gewSum = ~ sum(persGew)/1e5, 
                 uWHK = ~ n_distinct(id_intern[.x > 0]),
                 uWHKExp = ~ n_distinct(id_intern[(paste0("exp", cur_column()))>0])
              )
  ))
```

I hope you can recognize what I intend to do here. I take the columns starting with "pw" and count the distinct cases that have a value >0.
My problem is now that my condition in the term `id_intern[(paste0("exp", cur_column()))>0]` does not work the way I hoped, i.e. it always yields true. I tried to unquote the `paste0("exppw", cur_column())` so that it reads:

```
rt2020_2 %>% 
  select(id_intern, persGew, ges, matches("exppw...._1003"), matches("pw...._1003")) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("pw"), 
               list(
                 gewSum = ~ sum(persGew)/1e5, 
                 uWHK = ~ n_distinct(id_intern[.x > 0]),
                 uWHKExp = ~ n_distinct(id_intern[!!(paste0("exp", cur_column()))>0])
              )
  ))
```

But this leads to an error:

```
Error: `cur_column()` must only be used inside `across()`.
```

Can you help me? Or is there a better approach to my Problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems. It's not clear what you want in gewSum. Is that sum(persGew) or sum of all the columns that start with pw? Same for uWHK etc. Is it distinct counts of what's in the pw column or the id_intern column?

Also, it's not a good idea to use `[ ]` inside summarise. Probably better to `mutate` and create a few columns that serve as checks for your criteria.

Comment: Okay, I see I was not clear enough. Sorry for that.
`gewSum` is meant to be the sum of `persGew`. The variable `persGew` holds a weight for every person in my dataframe.
`uWHK` is the distinct number of person that have a value > 0 in the column that starts with `pw...`

You propose to create columns for the criteria but that would result in a big overhead of columns, wouldn't it? I just think about how to do that. If I use `mutate` I will have to use the square brackets again or am I wrong?